# Amazon API -- Can I search Category ALL - Other than DVD etc?

Tags: api, amazon-selling-partner-api

I Am trying to build play with API code from Amazon -- I am a noob at this --

I have created a product search using the simple lookup code, and have gone though and set the  search field form a form submission works fine, how ever I don't want to set a category Like I am currently below to say DVD, BABY MUSIC, I wish to set to ALL is this possible?

include("amazon_api_class.php");

```
$obj = new AmazonProductAPI(); -- I have edited this and added ALL as a category in here  

try
{
    $result = $obj->searchProducts($query,
                                   AmazonProductAPI::BABY, -- I can change this to DVD or MUSIC and it works but if i set to ALL i get errors?
                                   "TITLE"); - tryed changing this to KEYWORD doesnt work!
}
catch(Exception $e)
```

Any Help Would Be nice.

Thanks
Carl

OK --- updated -- ANd I belive I have to use KEYWORD when USING ALL so I have added this in

```
case "KEYWORD" :  $parameters = array("Operation"     => "ItemSearch",
                                                    "Title"         => $search,
                                                    "SearchIndex"   => $category,
                                                    "ResponseGroup" => "Small",
                                                    "MerchantId" => "All",
                                                        "Condition"=>"New",
                                                        'Keywords' => $searchTerm);
```

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /data/ADMINwhere2shoponline/www/include/amazon.php on line 23
still get this error?
carl

Answer (score 0):

Carl, 
You should be able to use ALL as the search parameter, but you need to make sure that the number of `ItemPage` you are requesting is not more than 5 or it will return an error. All other categories allow up to 10, but ALL is limited to 5.

Check that and see if you yet your problem resolved.

Comment: OK -- thats a bit poor but ok - is there one that isnt resticted do you know?
On another note I can't find the parameter ItemPage anywhere, from what I can see I have 2 includes Amazon_api_class and aws_signed_request which as far as I can see no numbers are set or find that variable?
Maybe I need to set-it?
Carl
thanks